# Does Ukranian have other examples of Old Slavic / Ukranian к / х correspondence (къто > хто)?

Tags: приголосні

Does Ukranian have other examples of Old Slavic / Ukranian к / х correspondence (къто > хто)?

Comment: There is no `kto` in Old Church Slavonic. Did you mean `къто`? What have you researched so far?

Comment: @bytebuster, I suppose, the author means Proto-Slavic (*kъ-to = [*kъto](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/kъto)), not Church Slavonic.

Comment: @bytebuster Yes, I mean Old Church Slavonic къто  (kŭto). https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%8A%D1%82%D0%BE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "кт -> хт" dissimilation occurs in many cases: "доктор -> дохтор", "квоктати -> квохтати", "трактир -> трахтир". But mostly the dissimulated versions are local or colloquial. Only in some cases the dissimulated versions become the new standard (and I currently can't find other examples for "кт -> хт" than "кто -> хто").

Some other types of dissimilation (e.g. "кр -> хр": "хрест"; "ч(ь)н -> шн": "мірочшик", "рушник", "рушниця", "сердешний", "соняшник"; "зш -> жч": "дорожчий", "нижчий"; "сш -> шч": "вищий") become standard more often (I don't know why).